# Cannot fetch E-Mail from Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Cannot fetch E-Mail address from facebook SDK for some particular E-Mail accounts. The facebook account I am testing with do have their E-Mail address in facebook. I am having this issue for some particular accounts only. Is there any settings which I have to activate from facebook. To fetch E-Mail I am using PHP Facebook SDK, the code is listed below:

```
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
            'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
        ]);

        try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
            $response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=id,name,email', $access_token);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        $user = $response->getGraphUser();

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($user);
        exit;
```

If I use artdarek/oauth-4-laravel I can fetch the E-Mail address for the exceptional cases as well. But as the project is live I cannot Install the same in live server. Please suggest an alternative way out with PHP Facebook SDK.

Comment: `scope` is part of the login flow, using it where you are doing is nonsense.

Comment: that was by mistake I am testing the same... do you have a solution for the same.. even if I ignore scope its not working...

Comment: so do you ask for the email permission in the login process?